# Can I unit test RxJS functions without TestScheduler?

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, observable, rxjs

tl;dr is it possible to unit test this code without rewriting it?

http://jsbin.com/jezosegopo/edit?js,console

```
const keyUpObserver = ($input, fetchResults) => {
    const source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($input, 'keyup')
        .map(e => e.target.value)
        .filter(text => text.length > 2)
        .debounce(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged();

    return source.flatMapLatest(text => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetchResults(text)));
};
```

`keyUpObserver` in the above code is heavily based on the [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js) autocomplete example, and uses a debounce to prevent hammering the server.

I'm trying to unit test this function, but Sinon's useFakeTimers doesn't appear to be working.

```
const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

const $input = $('<input>');
const fetchResults = (text) => new Promise(resolve => resolve(text + ' done!'));

keyUpObserver($input, fetchResults).subscribe(text => console.log(text));

$input.val('some text').trigger('keyup');

clock.tick(500);

// Enough time should have elapsed to make this a new event
$input.val('some more text').trigger('keyup');
```

I'm guessing this isn't sinon-related either, rather that RxJS uses some internal clock which must be unaffected by an external fake clock.

Given that, is there anyway to unit test my keyUpObserver code without rewriting it to also take a scheduler (default in production, test in unit tests)?

---

Comment: Is there some reason you can't take the scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

...to approach an answer: it seems that RxJs is using the default/global `setTimeout` implementation which Sinon should be able to overwrite. At least that's what I'd say from reading the [`defiultscheduler's` code](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/modular/scheduler/defaultscheduler.js#L12) which it uses if you don't pass (as mentioned) an custom scheduler.

Still, I am a bit confused about the intend. From [this little fork](http://jsbin.com/zacite/edit?js,console) I'd expect only the 3rd trigger to actually fire something which it does or am I should out of line?

Comment: You are part right. While `setTimeout` is one of the options that `DefaultScheduler` can use, it will take whatever option will be most performant in that case. So while it is likely that `setTimeout` will be used, there is no guarantee that it will stay that way, and it won't be a behavior to rely on cross platform or in the future.

Comment: Hi both, thanks a lot for the responses.

tdeekens: I might be wrong but it seems like it's caching those methods as soon as the file is loaded, so when I try and stub out the clock with sinon it's already too late. As for the intent, if you change the last clock.tick to 400, that should be enough to overcome the debounce and send a separate event... but it doesn't.

paulpdaniels: no _huge_ reason I can't pass the scheduler, it just feels like I'm having to rewrite my code artificially to allow unit testing.